# intermittent uninitialized constant error in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In one of my application, there are three tabs and when any of the tab is pressed, it shows some information by making a post call to corresponding service.

The controller for tab1 is as follows (Only small part is shown)

```
def tab1_results
  response = tab1_service_wrapper.get_tab1_result(params)
```

The controller for tab2 is as follows

```
def tab2_results
  search_params = JSON.parse(params[:searchParams])
  response = tab2_service_wrapper.get_tab2_result(search_params)
```

In each of the service wrappers we convert the input provided into JSON format and make a call to the respective services.

But recently I have observed that pressing tab1 repeatedly triggers the following error.

```
uninitialized constant ServiceInitializerModule::Tab1ServiceWrapper
```

This is observed only sometimes with tab1. This is not the case with tab2.

My question is can passing params directly to downstream be the cause for this issue?

Comment: It seems unlikely that passing `params` directly is the cause of the uninitialized constant error.

Comment: It only occurs sometimes not always. and the only difference that I could find in tab1 and tab2 is the way params are passed. So that why I wanted to confirm the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not related to the above. I was missing the require statement of Tab1ServiceWrapper. Adding the require statement fixed the issue.